# Voltages look like overclocking; is voltage control via a script possible?

Tags: scripts, sensors, overclocking

I see that my voltages look like overclocking. I want to know if what I have is right or not, because I always have errors with my voltages. I have a 600W power supply.

- CDROM does not work sometimes
- Onboard graphics card sucks
- IDE And SATA are too slow

## Existing Script?

Is there any script that helps me to configure voltages? I'm not so proficient in Bash.
Here's an example of how I'd like to interact with the script:

```
1.Cpu1
2....

Enter Number to configure
1
Enter Voltage
1.8 V
Press Enter to Finish
```

## My sensors output:

```
acpitz-virtual-0



Adapter: Virtual device

temp1:        +40.0°C  (crit = +125.0°C)


coretemp-isa-0000

Adapter: ISA adapter

Core 0:       +48.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

Core 1:       +48.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)


it8718-isa-0290

Adapter: ISA adapter

in0:          +1.20 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +4.08 V)

in1:          +1.86 V  (min =  +1.28 V, max =  +1.68 V)  ALARM  <-- This is what i mean

in2:          +3.38 V  (min =  +2.78 V, max =  +3.78 V)

+5V:          +2.98 V  (min =  +2.67 V, max =  +3.26 V)

in4:          +2.98 V  (min =  +2.50 V, max =  +3.49 V)

in5:          +0.06 V  (min =  +0.58 V, max =  +1.34 V)  ALARM  <---Really toooo low

in6:          +0.10 V  (min =  +1.04 V, max =  +1.36 V)  ALARM  <----Tooo low too!

5VSB:         +2.94 V  (min =  +2.67 V, max =  +3.26 V)

Vbat:         +3.09 V  

fan1:           0 RPM  (min =   10 RPM)  ALARM  <--I dont have a Fan 1

fan2:        1859 RPM  (min =   10 RPM)

fan3:           0 RPM  (min =   10 RPM)  ALARM  <--I dont have a Fan 3

temp1:        +32.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +126.0°C)  sensor = thermal diode

temp2:        +38.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +112.0°C)  sensor = thermistor

temp3:        -47.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +112.0°C)  sensor = thermistor

cpu0_vid:    +1.219 V
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Based on [psusi's response](http://askubuntu.com/a/94374/18612), it might be useful to know what motherboard your computer has. If you can find out the brand and model you have and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/94329/edit) that information back into your question, it could be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not change them, unless you have an overclocking motherboard, and then there will be options in the bios.  Obviously the in5 and in6 are wrong, probably because they are not connected on your motherboard.  The alarm value for in1 is probably also just set wrong.  There is really no telling what the correct value is supposed to be without reverse engineering your motherboard.